# How to mix 2 json response to 1 list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to mix 2 json response to 1 list in flutter?

I have 2 json https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&page=1&order=Desc and https://catfact.ninja/facts?limit=10.

Need create 1 model list with ['catimageurl'] from first and ['catfact'] from second  .

I try this code but catqfact return null

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

class CatsModel {
  final String caturl;
  final String catqfact;

  CatsModel({this.caturl, this.catqfact});

  factory CatsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return CatsModel(caturl: jsonData['url'], catqfact: jsonData['fact']);
  }
}

Future<List<CatsModel>> getCat() async {
  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&page=1&order=Desc');
  var response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List cats = json.decode(response.body);
    return cats.map((cat) => CatsModel.fromJson(cat)).toList();
  } else
    throw Exception('Json data download error');
}

Future<List<CatsModel>> getCatFact() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://catfact.ninja/facts?limit=10');
  var response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List catsFacts = json.decode(response.body);
    return catsFacts.map((cat) => CatsModel.fromJson(cat)).toList();
  } else
    throw Exception('Json data download error');
}
```

Comment: Hi There. It is not clear what you want your final json to be. Update your question with a small sample of what you want in your final json.

Answer (score 0):

you just need one function, since you have to combine data anyway.

```
Future<List<CatsModel>> getCatData() async {
  var imagesUri = Uri.parse('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&page=1&order=Desc');
  var factsUri = Uri.parse('https://catfact.ninja/facts?limit=10');

  var imagesResponse = await http.get(imagesUri);
  var factsResponse = await http.get(factsUri);

  if (imagesResponse.statusCode == 200 && factsResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    List images = json.decode(imagesResponse.body);
    List facts = json.decode(factsResponse.body)['data'];

    List<CatsModel> cats = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      cats.add(CatsModel(caturl: images[i]['url'], catqfact: facts[i]['fact']));
    }
    return cats;
  } else
    throw Exception('Json data download error');
}
```

Here is the pastebin link for the [full working code](https://pastebin.com/gEYBHy1P)

This is what it looks like.

Comment, if you feel you have doubt about any part. I'll explain.

[image]